# passing js value to another php page using java script and receiving value

Tags: javascript, php

I want to to pass a js variable to another page ..what to do..code is given bellow..

**Code**

`

```
$('#disInfo').on('click','tr',function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    var result=  obj.find('td').eq(1).html();
    window.location.href='http://localhost/Trying/search_cus.php';
});
```

`

I want to send the value of result variable with page link and how to receive the value in another page

Comment: if you are in control of both pages you can set a cookie or localstorage variable to hold the javascript variable...  i do the same thing to verify password change requests

Answer (score 1):

You could pass it via an url parameter. If result contains html or characters that cannot be used in an url then you need to encode it first.

```
$('#disInfo').on('click','tr',function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    var result = encodeURIComponent( obj.find('td').eq(1).html() );
    window.location.href='http://localhost/Trying/search_cus.php?result=' + result;
});
```

On the target page you can get url parameters via `window.location.search` ... there's plenty of examples on stackoverflow on how to do that.

NOTE: be aware that the server will also get the request for `?result=whatever`. If the server side code processes this (eg PHP: `$_GET['result']`) you must ensure it sanitizes the value to prevent malicious code injection.

BTW, other ways of passing data is via cookies, sessionStorage, localStorage, etc.

Comment: plus one on the storage options.

Comment: if I want to send more then one value?

Comment: add more than one parameter or storage entry

Comment: can u please give the the code for passing two value?

Comment: var result2 = encodeURIComponent(obj.find('td').eq(whatever number it is).html());  window.location.href='localhost/Trying/search_cus.php?result=' + result +'&result2=' + result2;

Comment: can this two variable be received in php block?

Comment: Yes, see the comment I added. Php can access it via [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) for instance. Take security measures!!!